# What is the difference between using list and tuple in `.loc` operator of a single-indexed pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I checked the documentation for:

- [Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)
- [10 minutes to pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html)
- [pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

I couldn't find the differences in those pages or in any SO posts (that I could easily search for).

I'm aware that the [API reference page for pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) mentions the following as one of the allowed inputs:

> A list or array of labels, e.g. `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

I've seen parts of the documentation where tuples are used only in the case of a MultiIndex dataframe. There's no mention of tuple being used in the case of non-MultiIndex / single-indexed dataframe.

My confusion is because I can still use a tuple and list almost interchangeably. For example:

```py
data = [
    [ 2, 26, 55, 52],
    [82, 18, 63, 12],
    [36, 24, 78, 55],
    [83,  9, 68, 93],
    [95, 46, 29, 76],
]
df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=['col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c', 'col_d'])
```

The following code works as if I'd used list instead:

```py
df.loc[:, ('col_a', 'col_b')]

df.loc[:, ('col_a', 'col_b')] = None
```

I've seen errors in some cases. For instance, using `df[('col_a', 'col_b')]` instead of `df[['col_a', 'col_b']]` raises a `KeyError`. That's understandable.

Questions:

- But why does it work for `.loc` operator (specifically, the column part)?
- What are the caveats of using tuple in this way instead of the prescribed list approach?
- Is there a documentation / post / blog that talks about this behavior extensively?

Answer (score 1):

I think because bug,
`df.loc[:, ('col_a', 'col_b')]` should raise error like `df[('col_a', 'col_b')]`

---

There is many another ways for select in Index and MultiIndex and some ways need discussion, why raise or not error.

[BUG: Index and MultiIndex KeyError cases and discussion #39775](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39775) .

Simple Index

> Since the introduction of KeyError for missing keys in an index there have been quite a few use cases from different issues. I will try and link some of the issues if I see them.

> My view is that KeyErrors for Index is fine, but MultiIndexes should be treated differently: you cannot always raise a KeyError for a single keys in a MultiIndex slice since a MultiIndex cannot always be reindexed.

MultiIndex

> MultiIndexing is different. You cannot always reindex for one of two reasons:

> The number of possible combinations of the index level values exceeds ram and is computationally slow.
> If you are to add in a value or set of values to a MultiIndex level the process is ambiguous and expanding all combinations will lead to above problems.

> For example, consider the MultiIndex levels: (a,b), (x,y,z). There are a maximum of 6 index tuples but practically one will work with indexes of much less than the maximum combinations (Since the combinations scale exponentially with the number of levels). Your MultiIndex is thus [(a,x), (a,z), (b,x), (b,y)].

> I think you need to be able to index MultiIndexes with keys that are missing. As a rule I would suggest that slices which are an iterable do not yield KeyErrors. Here is a summary of some of the observances below for current behaviour:

```
[a, y] : KeyError
[a, [y]] : KeyError but should return empty (a in level0)
[[a], y] : KeyError but should return empty (y in level1)
[[a], [y]] : KeyError but should return empty 
[a, !] : KeyError 
[a, [!]] : returns empty
[[a], !] : KeyError (maybe OK since ! not in level1)
[[!], x] : returns empty (x in level1)
[[!], [!]] : returns empty
[!, !] : KeyError
```

Comment: I should've been clearer. The expression `df.loc[:, ('col_a', 'col_b')]` doesn't raise an error at all. It works as if I'd used `df.loc[:, ['col_a', 'col_b']]`. And that's where my confusion is.

Comment: Wrong "answer". OP says the otherwise clearly

Comment: This should have been a wrong comment, anyway.

Comment: @Either - I see, you are deleted account Neither.

Comment: @m01010011 - You are right, answer was changed.

Comment: Thanks for so much of effort, but sorry, it still doesn't answer my question (nor it is, I feel, relevant at all). I'm confused about using tuples instead of lists for selected columns in the `.loc` operator, solely in the case of single-indexed dataframes.

Comment: @m01010011 - yes, understand. My answer is you find one of problematic ways for selecting, in answer is show multiple problems here. So in another words - it is buggy.

Comment: @m01010011 `df.loc[:, ('col_a', 'col_b')]` should raise error like `df[('col_a', 'col_b')]`